# Data Copy From REST API Working Very Slow-ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy a data from a REST client to the azure data lake using ADF. I am using the Copy activity and HTTP linked service. It takes aroung 15 sec for a file to download. Which is very slow.

I had increased the DTU but had no impact on the data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Each activity in data factory has an overhead of around 10 seconds. This is not "very slow" as it is meant to move any amount of data from source to sink. The main question is, those 15 seconds have an impact on your solution?

Also consider that its not a streaming or a real time tool, if you are looking for quick response times you might find stream analytics useful.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I do agree, but 10 seconds to download a file is too high. Also I dont think stream analytics can download file from REST API unless I am wrong. I am looking for suggestions on how to increase the speed. Thanks

Comment: Its not 10 seconds to download a file, it takes 10 seconds to start the activity. After that time, the file is probably being downloaded in 1 or 2 seconds. As far as I know, its not possible to lower that time.